# How can I disable all CSS that can affect my widgets on another website?

Tags: javascript, css, widget

I'm building JavaScript widgets that are supposed to be added onto other people's websites.

I style my widgets by dynamically adding a CSS to the pages they're on.

For example,

My CSS code below applies to a DIV inside my widget:

```
.myWidget { background-color: red; }
```

But a CSS file outside my own on a remote page might have:

```
div { border: 5px solid green; }
```

The CSS above would also apply to my widgets. How can I disable all other CSS outside my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be Using shadow DOM

[Shadow DOM MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

An important aspect of web components is encapsulation — being able to keep the markup structure, style, and behavior hidden and separate from other code on the page so that different parts do not clash, and the code can be kept nice and clean. The Shadow DOM API is a key part of this, providing a way to attach a hidden separated DOM to an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`all` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) and the [`unset` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) to set each property's value to its initial value.

```css
.myWidget {
  all:unset;
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="myWidget">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, but would the "all:unset" disable all CSS applied to a div even though I didn't use a div selector in the example above (but myWidget instead)?

Comment: @jennie788 Unfortunately, it would.

Comment: Actually, that's what I want. I want to make sure that no CSS outside my own can affect my divs.